# Installing NodeJS on Linux RHEL(Release 6.6(Santiago)?

Tags: node.js, linux, sudo, yum, rhel

I'm trying to Install NodeJS on Linux RHEL(Release 6.6(Santiago)? Nothing seems to work. I download and extract the file(v.6.3.1). The I try to install with the command sudo yum install package_name. Nothing I try is working.

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat packages a number of technologies via "Software Collections" including node.js 0.10 and 4.4.  Details are here:  https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/2/html-single/2.2_Release_Notes/index.html

Also, these are part of the RHEL subscription.